# How do I code one import statement that the entire App recognises

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I remember reading somewhere but I cannot remember where exactly I need to write the import statement so that the whole App has access to it.  I have a AppHelper class which I want the whole app to see without importing it in every class file.

So I have tried to add it to my .pch file but I get the following error messages:

"_kGTMHTTPFetcherStatusDomain", referenced from: _kGTMHTTPFetcherStatusDomain$non_lazy_ptr in GTMHTTPFetcher.o (maybe you meant: _kGTMHTTPFetcherStatusDomain$non_lazy_ptr) "_kGTMHTTPFetcherRetryDelayStartedNotification", referenced from: _kGTMHTTPFetcherRetryDelayStartedNotification$non_lazy_ptr in GTMHTTPFetcher.o (maybe you meant: _kGTMHTTPFetcherRetryDelayStartedNotification$non_lazy_ptr)

This is my .pcb file:

```
//
// Prefix header for all source files of the 'SplitView' target in the 'SplitView' project
//
#import <Availability.h>


#ifndef __IPHONE_3_2
#warning "This project uses features only available in iPhone SDK 3.2 and later."
#endif


#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#endif

#import "AppCache.h"
```

Comment: Move the import into the #ifdef __OBJC__

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add that import into application precompiled header (e.g. YourApplication.pch)

Comment: I tried that but as soon as I put it in the .pch file i get this:    "_kGTMHTTPFetcherStatusDomain", referenced from:


      _kGTMHTTPFetcherStatusDomain$non_lazy_ptr in GTMHTTPFetcher.o


     (maybe you meant: _kGTMHTTPFetcherStatusDomain$non_lazy_ptr)


  "_kGTMHTTPFetcherRetryDelayStartedNotification", referenced from:


      _kGTMHTTPFetcherRetryDelayStartedNotification$non_lazy_ptr in GTMHTTPFetcher.o


     (maybe you meant: _kGTMHTTPFetcherRetryDelayStartedNotification$non_lazy_ptr)

Comment: try to clean your target and rebuild it

Comment: Update your question to show what you're putting in your .pch file.